# Mechanics differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This question is related to a mechanics problem for which I have already done the dynamics side of it and have now reduced it down to this but I'm having trouble evaluating this differential equation.

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\sqrt{(2g\sin\alpha) s}$$

I can see that I need to separate variables but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ function of $t$ or of $s$ ? If not the ODE is separable : use the straightforwardl integration method.

Comment: $\alpha$ was just the angle that the plane was inclined at, so no it isn't a function of $t$ or $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\sqrt{(2g\sin\alpha) s}$$

$$\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s}}=\sqrt{2g\sin\alpha}\:dt$$

$$\int\frac{ds}{\sqrt{s}}=\sqrt{2g\sin\alpha}\int dt$$
$$2\sqrt{s}=\sqrt{2g\sin\alpha}\:t+\text{constant}$$